# Shell script takes variable as a command

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm coding an extremely simple shell script and it doesn't really work as it should. Here are the contents:

```
# Defining base project directory
BASE_DIR=/path/to/proj;
PRODUCTION_DIR = $BASE_DIR/out/production/dir;

# Generating headers
javah -classpath $PRODUCTION_DIR -d $BASE_DIR/jni/include com.my.class.Name

#     Building native libs
ndk-build
```

Paths are correct, it works if I remove **$PRODUCTION_DIR**, if I'll run it like this, it says:

```
line 3: PRODUCTION_DIR: command not found
...
```

Does any one know what's wrong?

Comment: If this is a bash or dash or sh script, you do not need to (and probably shouldn't) terminate lines with semicolons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove whitespace,

```
PRODUCTION_DIR=$BASE_DIR/out/production/dir
```

Otherwise you're trying to run `PRODUCTION_DIR` with parameters `=` and `$BASE_DIR/out/production/dir`

Also, remove the ;'s at end of line, they're redundant

Comment: +1 and also, you should be using a build tool like `make` for this kind of thing. Not a shell script.

Comment: @Noufal Ibrahim, to generate headers from java sources and compile ndk project... make?

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with java and have no experience with the ecosystem but I'm guessing that you're doing some kind of build and so recommend a build system like make (which is what I'm used to).

Comment: "if you want to change the oil in your car, you should first learn how to build a car repair shop."